# Add or remove class on list item when user scroll through particular section in fixed division

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div class="contact-details" id="contact-details">
    <ul>
        <li class="call"><a href="#"><span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span></a></li>
        <li class="email"><a href="#"><span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span></a></li>
        <li class="skype"><a href="#"><span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span></a></li>
        <li class="run"><a href="#"><span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    if (scroll > windowHeight) {
        $('.contact-details ul li').addClass('active');
        alert("hello");
    } else {
        $('.contact-details ul li').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

here I want when the fixed division scroll through the page as it is fixed. When items in list scroll through banner a class should be added on list-item and remove class when it scrolls back to the banner section.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed your banner is at the top of your page...

You have to look at what you compare.
If you compare the scrolled amount with the innerHeight of the window, you'll have to scroll a big while before having a `true`!

Usually, the innerHeight of a window is way bigger than its padding/margin.

So I suggest you to compare the scrolled amount with the position of the element to impact minus the outerHeight of the fixed element that comes across.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  //windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
  var bannerHeight = $("#banner").outerHeight();

  
  $('.contact-details ul li').each(function(){
    if (scroll > $(this).offset().top - bannerHeight) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      //console.log("hello");
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.contact-details{
  height:2000px;
  padding-top:100px;
}
#banner{
  height:70px;
  width:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:12px;
}
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="banner">Banner</div>

<div class="contact-details" id="contact-details">
    <ul>
      <li class="call">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="email">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="skype">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="run">
        <a href="#">
          <span>+49 (6131) 143 83 25</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't know why this answer is still not accepted, this worked for me like a charm. Thanks mate!